# when I created logstash offline pack, it dosen't contain the change

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to modify the logstash integration rabbitmq plugin and use it
(https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-integration-rabbitmq.git)

I modified the inputs/rabbitmq.rb and confirmed that it works properly on my local.

I created an offline pack to upload it to the server, but the modified contents are not applied to the offline pack.

No errors when installing gem files or creating offline packs

After installing as an offline pack, when I checked rabbitmq.rb (vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-rabbitmq-7.1.0-java/lib/logstash/inputs/),
the file modification time seems to have changed, but the modifications have not been applied.

I don't know why it can't only be applied to offline packs
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: do you have any reason to use sources from github? you can easily install logstash with deb package. it has rabbitmq plugin by default.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/de/downloads/logstash

Comment: yes I know rabbitmq plugin is default. but I need to modify it to manage input history. so I modified rabbitmq.rb file, built gem, and installed it into logstash. but only offline pack is abnormal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved this problem using JRuby.
Before Ruby was installed on my local, and I used it for building gem.
After changing JRuby, the offline pack is ok.